# Solve the differential equation $ xy^2y'=x+4 $

Tags: calculus

Solve the differential equation: $$ xy^2y'=x+4 $$

Because at my level I only deal with integration with respect to one variable, I divided by x to get $ y^2 y' = \frac {x+4}{x} $. I could multiply both sides by $dx$ to get $y^2dy= \frac {x+4}{x} dx $, but would it then be valid to take the integral as follows?:
 $$ \int  y^2dy =\int \frac {x+4}{x} dx $$

I'm not sure whether this is correct so far, please advise

Comment: It is correct so far

Comment: Yes, correct.  This is a separable equation.

Answer (score 6):

You're almost done (everything you've done is indeed correct). And yes, it is not only valid to take the integral of each side, that's precisely how to proceed.

Integrate the left side with respect to $y$, and integrate the right side with respect to $x$:

$$\int  y^2\,dy =\int \frac {x+4}{x} \,dx$$

$$\iff \int y^2\,dy = \int \left(1+ \frac 4x\right)\,dx$$

$$\iff \frac{y^3}{3} = x+ 4\ln|x| + c$$

That's all there is to it.  We can multiply each side of the equation by $3$ to get $$y^3 = 3x + 12\ln|x|+C = 3x+ \ln(|x|^{12}) + C = 3x + \ln(x^{12})+C$$

Comment: Thanks. Wouldn't you have 3x+12ln|x|+C after multiplying by 3?

Comment: Yes...I corrected my typo as you were writing your comment!  Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

$y^2 dy= \int \left(1+ \frac{4}{x}\right) dx$

That should be easy to integrate.

Comment: You are missing another integral symbol, aren't you?